# combo box does not refresh when observable collection changes

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have a wpf desktop app.

I have a dropdown box and its items source is set to an observable collection.

The purpose is to display a list of users.
I have a button on that form that will delete the selected user.
It sets the field 'Active' to '0' where '1' is not deleted.

The problem is that even though I can see the observable collection has been reduced by 1. But visually the dropdown shows all the original user states.

This is my XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Users}" DisplayMemberPath="Login" 
                 SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedManagerUser}"  />
```

This is the VM bit of it:

```
public ObservableCollection<UserRecord> Users
{
    get
    {
        return (from users in UserRecord.Get().Where(d => d.Active == 1)
                     select new UserRecord
                     {
                         FName = users.FName,
                         SName = users.SName,
                         UserRecordId = users.UserRecordId,
                         Login = users.Login,
                         IsAdmin = users.IsAdmin,
                         UserRef = users.UserRef,
                         Disabled = users.Disabled,
                         Branch = users.Branch,
                         Department = users.Department,
                         Position = users.Position,                                
                         Salt = users.Salt,
                     }).OrderBy(d => d.Login).ToList();

    }
    set {
        _Users =  value; RaisePropertyChanged(InformedWorkerCommon.Constants.VM_Users); }
}
```

My POCO/Model:

```
public class UserRecord
{
    public int UserRecordId { get; set; }
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string SName { get; set; }
    public string Login { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
    public int IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public string UserRef { get; set; }
    public int Disabled { get; set; }
    public string Branch { get; set; }
    public string Position { get; set; }
    public int Active { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string ServerRef { get; set; }
    public DateTime ServerTS { get; set; }
}
```

This is the code that sets the Active field to '0':

**my test involves pre-loading with 2 users**

```
private void DeleteUser()
{
    try
    {
```

**at this point the Users count is 2**

```
        UserRecord.Save(new UserRecord()
                {
                    UserRef=UserRef,
                    Branch = Branch,
                    Department = Department,
                    Disabled = Disabled == true ? 1 : 0,
                    FName = FName,
                    IsAdmin = 0,
                    Login = Login,
                    Position = Position,
                    SName = SName,
                    Active = 0,                           
                });
```

**at this point the Users count is 1 but the dropdown still shows 2 users**

```
                DisplayInfoMessage(Properties.Resources.Deleted);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //handle the error
    }
}
```

I am relatively new to wpf so I could be doing a right howler here?

Comment: Is the value of InformedWorkerCommon.Constants.VM_Users "Users", as to notify the combobox the binding has been changed? You do not seem to be 'setting' the property anywhere as your getter is just reading everything again from database. You do not really need a setter for the Users property, it is enough to notify the correct binding has been changed from the delete function.

Comment: I am a bit surprised that a `Delete()` method is implemented as `Save(new UserRecord{...})`. However, assuming that `Save` will still do the right thing, probably you only need to update the `Binding` in your `ComboBox`. `ObservableCollection` will not notify automatically when only a property of an item has changed. I think the code of `UserRecord.Save` would be helpful here.

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion. There is a reason why the delete is as it is and possibly all for the wrong reasons :) I will check when I get back to the office. Thank u

Comment: @JanneMatikainen quite right about the setter. Will remove when back and check that constant value. Thank u

Comment: Does this code compile? Your `Users` getter is expected to return `ObservableCollection<UserRecord>` but instead it returns `List<UserRecord>`. You can't implicitly cast `List` to `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Hi it does compile which means I pasted it wrong. Definitely an observable collection. Will correct when back. Thanks for putting me right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create *one* single instance of your ObservableCollection and add and remove items from this single instance.

You could create the collection in the constructor of your view model and implement the property as a simple auto-implemented read-only property, e.g.:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Users = new ObservableCollection<UserRecord>((from users in UserRecord.Get().Where(d => d.Active == 1)
                                                      select new UserRecord
                                                      {
                                                          FName = users.FName,
                                                          SName = users.SName,
                                                          UserRecordId = users.UserRecordId,
                                                          Login = users.Login,
                                                          IsAdmin = users.IsAdmin,
                                                          UserRef = users.UserRef,
                                                          Disabled = users.Disabled,
                                                          Branch = users.Branch,
                                                          Department = users.Department,
                                                          Position = users.Position,
                                                          Salt = users.Salt,
                                                      }).OrderBy(d => d.Login).ToList());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<UserRecord> Users { get; }

}
```

Then the ComboBox bound to the Users property will get updated as you add or remove items from the source collection. But you should not create a new ObservableCollection each time the getter of the source property is called.

Comment: Thanks for educating me. Happy xmas :)